# Does Android save and restore instance state of some field automatically?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-savedstate

I have a RecyclerView with MyItem as holding the data for each rows in the RecyclerView, and everything is properly implemented and working fine.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>{
    protected final List<MyItem> items= new ArrayList<>();
    public MyAdapter (List<RVItem> list) {
        if (list != null) {
            items.addAll(list);
        }
    }
}
```

And the List items is passed from another object.

```
public class MyObject{
    private String otherThing;
    private List<MyItem> items;
    public someMethodToInitItems() {
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(...);
        items.add(...);
    }
    public createFragment() {
        Fragment f = new MyCustomFragment();
        f.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(items));
        // replace commit fragment...
    }
}
```

The problem here is when my Activity is restored, the field `private List<MyItem> items` in `MyObject` somehow magically get restored too, but field like `otherThing` is still null and not getting restored.
FYI, I did not explicitly save and restore `items` in any way. Also, `onSaveInstanceState` in `MyCustomFragment` is left untouched and not overridden from super.

Below is how I'm trying to save and restore the Fragment state from the Activity. That's it.

```
public class MyActivity{
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, tag, getLastFragment());
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            Fragment fg = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, tag);
        }
    }
}
```

So, I don't get it. Is Android system did this job? Save and restore the field `items` in `MyObject` automatically? Or there must be something else causing this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override onRetainNonConfigurationInstance method. This method could helps you to store your data

More details [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance())